# How to put more than one or condition in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Below are the cases to cover using regular expression:

**Case 1:** (3) x 4.5 mL Red Top Tubes.

**Case 2:** (3) 4mL Red Top Tubes.

**Case 3:** (3)- 4mL Red Top Tubes.

I have created regular expression to cover all these above cases:

But it is not working for '**Case 3** ' where separator is '-'

```
(\(([^)]+)\)(?:\s*x\s*|\s*|-)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)\s*ml\s([\w\s]+)[,\;\and\s]*)
```

**Output**
[image]

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match on `-` since second alternative `\s*` is an all-time match that satisfies engine right there. Your regex don't need all those alternations either:

```
\(([^)]+)\)\s*[x-]?\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*m[lL]\b([\w\s]+)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0wgH4/2)

Comment: Thanks you so much.